# Subtracting one address from another address in C

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, malloc, allocation

In a homework project, I have to subtract the address of one pointer from another.
Here is a piece of code I tried to write to subtract the heap of void* type, from a given metadata address. It's wrong somewhere.

```
metadata_t* getBuddy(metadata_t* ptr)
{
 metadata_t* offset = ptr - (char)heap;
 int h = (char)heap;
#ifdef DEBUG
 printf("ptr : %p\n", ptr);
 printf("heap : %p\n", heap);
 printf("offset: %p\n", offset);
 printf("char : %d\n", h);
 #endif
    return NULL;
}
```

Here is the output I get:

```
ptr   : 0x7fe7b3802440 
heap  : 0x7fe7b3802200 
offset: 0x7fe7b3802440 
char  : 0
```

Here is the output I EXPECTED:

```
ptr   : 0x7fe7b3802440 
heap  : 0x7fe7b3802200 
offset: 0x000000000240 
char  : 0x7fe7b3802200
```

Questions:

1) Why would the char output be zero? (Is this not what I am doing: casting the a pointer in single bytes, and then storing it into an int)

2) If this is not how you properly do the pointer arithmetic, how else would you accomplish the offset?

Edits:

1) Heap is defined as a int*, I think. This is the given piece of code that returns its value.

```
#define HEAP_SIZE 0x2000
void *my_sbrk(int increment) {

  static char *fake_heap = NULL;
  static int current_top_of_heap = 0;
  void *ret_val;

  if(fake_heap == NULL){
    if((fake_heap = calloc(HEAP_SIZE, 1)) == NULL) {
      return (void*)-1;
    }
  }
  ret_val=current_top_of_heap+fake_heap;
  if ((current_top_of_heap + increment > HEAP_SIZE) 
      || (current_top_of_heap+increment < 0)) {
    errno=ENOMEM;
    return (void*)-1;
  }
  current_top_of_heap += increment;
  return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense.  pointer - pointer does not give another pointer.  How is `heap` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic only makes sense for a specific type. In this example, the int type is size 4 but the pointer subtraction is only 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[2];
int *a, *b;

int main(void){
    a = &array [0];
    b = &array [1];
    printf ("Int size = %d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf ("Pointer difference = %d\n", b-a);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Int size = 4
Pointer difference = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Pointers arithmetic doesn't support the operation (pointer + pointer). The only operation allowed is (Pointer + Integer) so the result is a pointer.

To get the offset you need to cast both pointers to an integer type. And the resulting value is an integer not a pointer.

Example:

```
int offset = (int)ptr - (int)heap;

printf("ptr : %p\n", ptr);
printf("heap : %p\n", heap);
printf("offset: %d\n", offset);
```

Also the value of `heap` is too much large to be stored in a single byte and that's why casting it into  a `char` type returns the value zero.